# Crash when adding UITabBarController to window iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6

application works very good until i updated XCode to version 4.5 and the iOS 6 SDK.

the application are crashed with this output:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency',    reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View   <UIView: 0xad397b0; frame = (0 20; 320 460); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xad39810>> is associated with <UIViewController: 0xad39940>. Clear this association before associating this view with <RootViewController: 0x9e62f00>.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0xda012 0x1ea7e7e 0xd9deb 0xbc9309 0xc605ac 0xc5ca90 0x1661e8e 0x16619b7 0x168c428     0xd980cc 0x1ebb663 0xd545a 0xd96bcf 0xc5be37 0xc5c418 0xc5c648 0xc5c882 0xc5cb2a 0xc73ef5   0xc73fdb 0xc74286 0xc74381 0xc74eab 0xc74fc9 0xc75055 0xd7a3ab 0xbcb92d 0x1ebb6b0 0x405fc0   0x3fa33c 0x3fa150 0x3780bc 0x379227 0x41bb50 0xb9152f 0xa2afe 0xa2a3d 0x807c2 0x7ff44 0x7fe1b 0x2bef7e3 0x2bef668 0xb7b65c 0x2a6b 0x29d1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

the application are adding to the window login view, then the tab bar view with this code:

```
/* LOGIN VIEW ADD */

[window addSubview:[loginVC view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

/* LOGIN VIEW REMOVE AND ADD TAB BAR CONTROLLER */

[loginVC.view removeFromSuperview];
[window addSubview:[tabBarController view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

the application crashed after the remove and the add.

what apple do on iOS 6? why this is crashed?

Answer (score 0):

You are no longer supposed to add your view as a subview in the main window. Now, the proper thing to do is set your `rootController` to the `UIViewController` you want be well, the root one.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIViewController *myViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"RandomStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
    window.rootViewController = myViewController;
    return YES;
}
```

Most applications can do this the easy way though. If you have a Main Storyboard in your project (set in project file), it will automatically instantiate the initial view controller from that storyboard.

Comment: thanks, but i found what couse the problem. the viewcontroller's xib need to be only view and not a viewcontroller